# How to apply style for parent img element using CSS

Tags: css

I want to set width to my IMG using the outer div class. Since the structure between the outer div and image might be different from page to page.

What would be the best CSS syntax to achieve this?

```
<div class="my-div">
    <span class="my-variable-class">
        <a href="#" class="element-x">
            <img src="logo.png">
        </a>
    </span>
<div>
```

So far i'v got:

```
.my-div > img{
    width:200px !important;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? you want img width the same as `my-div`?

Comment: as far as I remember, it's impossible to go from child to parent in css

Comment: `.logo` is already `img` so `.logo > img` doesn't exist

Comment: i want to set the img to max with of 200px, without using the class on image.

Comment: `.my-div img { max-width: 200px }`? Seems too simple...

Comment: Don't use the direct child selector `>` if you don't know how many nested elements there is. But I can only have one child image, otherwise every img descendant of `.my-div` will be impacted

Comment: If that's correct, the title is very badly worded, please correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infuriatingly, there is no parent selector in CSS.

You need to put a class on your `img` containers and style that.

```
.img_container {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

I also recommend, though it's theoretically not supposed to be necessary:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Presuming we're talking about `max-width` because you're doing responsive design and you want the `img_container` to be nearly-full-width on mobile but not grow out of control on wider screens. For that, also give `img_container` a `width: 95%` (or whatever amount). This must come *before* the `max-width` limit.